# Android in app subscription status first month onward

Tags: android, android-studio, in-app-billing, android-billing

I have an android app using google in app monthly subscription, The subscription is working fine when user is subscribe successfully it will go through *public void onProductPurchased* so I can update the database, but the problem is first month onward where subscription is renewed, there is no function to know user is charged successfully or it is failed, shall I get the status of subscription from server api call to google? Or there is any other function or way to get the status?

```
bp.subscribe(MainActivity.this,"starterplan");

@Override
public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String s, @Nullable TransactionDetails transactionDetails) {
    String plan = s;
    //here I am updating the database for new successful subscription
}

@Override
public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {

}

@Override
public void onBillingError(int i, @Nullable Throwable throwable) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "SOME ERROR OCCURED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onBillingInitialized() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: leveraging the server API is our recommended best practice.

When subscription auto renews, here is what happens:

- TRIGGER: Both RTDN (server) and onPurchasesUpdated (Android) receive alerts.
- YOU: n/a. User should already have access to entitlement. But to be safe you should check with `playDeveloperApi.purchases.subscriptions.get` that `expiryTimeMillis` is in the future.

Longer version:

Google Play Billing informs apps of subscription state changes through multiple avenues:
 Android's `BillingClient.queryPurchases`, Android's `onPurchasesUpdated`, and server's [Real-Time Developer Notifications (RTDN)](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/realtime_developer_notifications). On the Android side, developers only know of a limited number of state changes and only if the user is in the app. But RTDN alerts the server as soon as the changes happen, which makes it the recommended listening channel. Nevertheless, whichever listening channel a developer uses, many subscription use-cases require a server-to-server component. Hence, the Google Play Developer API's [Purchases.subscriptions: get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get) function must be used to obtain the full meaning of a Purchase state change alert.